# In new Visual Studio for Mac - possible to create Windows Forms Application?

Tags: macos, winforms, visual-studio, xamarin

In new Visual Studio for Mac - how can I  create a Windows Forms Application - or the most similar thing to one? And in the latter case - can I open an old Windows Forms Application-project in this? This is for a student school task, where we are to open an old Windows Forms Project created as an example - run it and get inspired to create a new one. Is it possible to do so from the new Visual Studio for Mac?

Comment: There is no WinForms on Mac.

Comment: @mybirthname: https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-mac/

Comment: @SLaks Lol thanks for the link

Comment: Well, there is *kind of* WinForms on Mac.  The Mono guys had something kind of working before they decided to focus on GTK# and platform-specific UIs.  I know because I have run a simple WinForms app I wrote on my Mac under Mono.  But practically speaking, no, you don't want to try WinForms development on a Mac (except within a Windows VM), and MS certainly does not support it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to open and run in Visual Studio for Mac a Windows Forms project created in Visual Studio on Windows. It may work in some simple cases, but generally it is not supported, and when it crashes, nobody will help you. I tried to migrate my WinForms project and stopped after getting a crash when trying to show a NotifyIcon:

```
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
```

Unfortunately, it is a dead end.